# Using the values of first $_POST in sending it another $_POST

Tags: php, post

I have to use values which I obtained from first `$_POST` call in a second `$_POST` method to another value.
for example I am getting `$location = $POST['location_name'];`

I want to be able to pass the $location while doing another $_POST which leads to second form.

```
1st Form -> 2nd Form($_POST['location-name']) -> 3rd form $_POST['location-name']
```

But I am losing the value while going to the 3rd form.

How can I get the value in the 3rd form?

Thanks

Comment: HTTP is a stateless protocol. No data is persisted anywhere on the server between requests.

Comment: does it have to be by post, or can you simply assign `$_SESSION['location-name'] = $_POST['location-name'];` and use `$_SESSION['location-name']` later on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I wouldn't recommend this for security reasons... there *IS* a way to do this using POST

You could write a bunch of hidden fields on the second page that contain the values of the previous form post, something like this:

```
foreach($_POST as $field => $val) {
  echo('<input type="hidden" name="'.$field.'" value="'.$value.'" />);
}
```

This will create a hidden field for each value in the previous `$_POST` array, and send it along with the new forms data, so the second `$_POST` will contain all values from the first and second forms

Answer (score 3):

As others have stated, you cannot use POST for this. Session would work better.

If you really have to use POST, then the only way to really get around this is to load a page that fills out a form with the POST variables and then automatically post that form with JavaScript to the location variable. This form would have to have one hidden value for each POST variable with the same name attribute as the key in the $_POST array.

See duellsy's answer for a more code orientated description.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [session variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) for that - take the values submitted in the first post, store them in `$_SESSION` and take them from there after the second post.

Answer (score 1):

Only the client can do the POST. And you get these POST variables only when the client executes a POST to your server.

So you should find another solution. You can use sessions to store client specific information, so you can recognize the client when it does another request to your server.

```
$_SESSION['variable_name'];
```

You can also include the variable for the fist POST in the the form for the next POST. This is cleaner if it's not something you would have to use all over your website but just for this flow.

Be aware though, you should always validate data posted by clients, you should look out for [cross-site request forgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).